# Is there a reason for the recent drop in acceptance rate for answers

Tags: discussion

Recently I have started seeing that users do not accept working answers, even though the answers are correct and complete (example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602168/spring-data-persist-object-in-hbase/36674073#36674073), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416324/implementing-custom-authentication-in-spring-security/36417101#36417101)), upvoted by other users (example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028901/difference-between-spring-jtatransactionmanager-and-hibernatetransactionmanager/36029252#36029252), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720392/scala-and-java-in-same-project/35720920#35720920)) and in some cases awarded bounties (example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257554/discriminating-users-without-authentication-in-spring/36145483#36145483), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605934/error-406-in-spring-mvc-migration-from-spring-3-0-5-to-spring-4-2-4/35822685#35822685)). In many of these cases, the answer is the only provided answer and the users even acknowledge the validity of the answers in comments, but still do not accept the answer.

I was checking my own profile and have found that only 8 out of my last 25 answers have been accepted, even though most of them have multiple upvotes and even bounties. Out of the previous 25 answers, 13 were accepted and going back even further, 19 of the previous 25 answers were accepted. Things seem to have changed drastically in the last year or so.

I would assume that this lack of answer acceptance would discourage users from answering questions, leading to answer rates dropping.

In many cases I can see that the posters are only interested in someone else writing code for them. I personally skip those questions and where appropriate vote to close the questions off as well, so I am not worried about those kind of questions.

Have others noticed a similar trend and is there any explanation for the apparent drop in acceptance rates?

Comment: Without data this is anecdotal. You can use Stack Exchange Data Explorer to get more extensive trend data. Remember to take into account that some answers are accepted years later.

Comment: I really dont understand why someone wouldnt accept an answer even when it is the right one. Mabey some reminder for them would be good. Something like you have 4 questions with answers and should mark the right one?

Comment: here is a statistic, among the 4 link provided, 2 are from 2 new users, 1 quite low rep. So we can guess that 75% of your 4 link are from users that aren't really in the community of SO be are just here for answers, so they probably don't care about that.

Comment: @AndreasA. Just because the answer works doesn't mean that it's the best way or even a good way of doing things. Personally, I would love to see more answers try to convince me that they are valuable enough to deserve the check mark. I have a few open-ended type questions that I feel this applies to.

Comment: @Laurel I know its a valid point was just a suggestion. Becouse i think if someone takes the time to answer a question the questioner should honor it in some way. Or at least say thanks or something like that.

Comment: @andreas That's not how SO works.  We don't reward answers for trying, we reward answers for *succeeding*.